# Graphviz, GEF4 and build paths in Java

Tags: java, graphviz, dot, zest

I wrote this java code to display a simple graph using Graphviz and GEF4 framework. What's important, I am using Window Builder in Eclipse too. I created SWT/JFace Java project, then converted it into Plug-in project.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.gef4.dot.DotImport;
import org.eclipse.gef4.graph.*;
import org.eclipse.gef4.zest.fx.*;
import org.eclipse.gef4.layout.*;
import org.eclipse.gef4.layout.algorithms.*;


public class Code1 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    Shell shell = new Shell();
    shell.setSize(450, 300);
    shell.setText("SWT Application");
    shell.setLayout(null);


            Graph.Builder graph2 = new Graph.Builder().attr(ZestProperties.GRAPH_LAYOUT, new SpringLayoutAlgorithm());
            new DotImport("digraph{1->2}").into(graph2);
            new DotImport("node[label=zested]; 2->3; 2->4").into(graph2);
            new DotImport("edge[style=dashed]; 3->5; 4->6").into(graph2);
            //SpringLayoutAlgorithm SLA= new SpringLayoutAlgorithm(); 
            graph2.build();


    shell.open();
    shell.layout();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I have errrors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/emf/ecore/resource/ResourceSet
at org.eclipse.gef4.dot.DotImport.load(DotImport.java:81)
at org.eclipse.gef4.dot.DotImport.loadFrom(DotImport.java:63)
at org.eclipse.gef4.dot.DotImport.init(DotImport.java:55)
at org.eclipse.gef4.dot.DotImport.<init>(DotImport.java:46)
at program2.Code2.main(Code2.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.ResourceSet
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 5 more
```

I found that I need to add build paths (jar files with needed libraries) in Build Path. So I added. I added also all dependencies. But it still doesn't work. Have you got any idea, what could I miss? Thank you for any idea!

Comment: I would be really grateful for any idea, any tip! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you should find org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.ResourceSet lib and add file jar to elipse.